# How do i fix Infinite yield possibility?

Tags: lua, roblox

The following code is in a script inside of a Drive Seat & when the player is goes to sit in the seat it gives out the following output

"Infinite yield possible on 'Workspace.Car4.DriveSeat:WaitForChild("Humanoid")"

```
local character = script.Parent
local humanoid = character:WaitForChild("Humanoid")

function onSeated(isSeated,Seat)
    if humanoid ~= nil then
    local p = game.Players:FindFirstChild(n.Name)
        if p.Team.Name == "Thieves" then
            game.StarterGui.ThiefWinScreen.Frame.TextLabel.Script.Disabled = false
        end
    end
end
humanoid.Seated:Connect(onSeated(isSeated, Seat))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You refer to the [Roblox manual](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/Instance/WaitForChild) and find:

> **Instance:WaitForChild(childName, timeOUt)**
>
> Returns the child of the Instance with the given name. If the child
> does not exist, it will yield the current thread until it does.
> If the timeOut parameter is specified, this function will return nil and time out after timeOut seconds elapsing without the child being found.

> If a call to this function exceeds 5 seconds without returning, and no
> timeOut parameter has been specified, a warning will be printed to the
> output that the thread may yield indefinitely; this warning takes the
> form Infinite yield possible on 'X:WaitForChild("Y")', where X is the
> parent name and Y is the child object name.

So to avoid this warning provide a value for `timeOut` or make sure the child is found in less than 5 seconds.

Comment: It's also worth double-checking the spelling and capitalization of the object you are looking for.