# ROBLOX INFINITE YIELD Infinite yield possible on 'Players.Aiman123boss.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Main")'

Tags: roblox

i get this infinte yield:
Infinite yield possible on 'Players.Aiman123boss.PlayerGui:WaitForChild("Main")'

i want to fix it so heres my script:

```
local pg = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
local Main = pg:WaitForChild("Main")
for i, v in pairs(Main.PetShop.ScrollingFrame:GetChildren()) do
    if v.Name ~= "Template" and v:IsA("Frame") then
        v.PetPrice.Text = game.ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Pets"):FindFirstChild(v.Name).Price.Value
        v.PetName.Text = game.ServerStorage:WaitForChild("Pets"):FindFirstChild(v.Name).Name
    end
end
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i fix Infinite yield possibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471149/how-do-i-fix-infinite-yield-possibility)

Answer (score 0):

You are waiting on the object "Main" here:
`local Main = pg:WaitForChild("Main")`

Roblox determined that it's possible that "Main" will never be found, because the object doesn't exist completely. Try checking your object hierarchy and determine if the following path exists:
`game.StarterGui.Main`

If it exists, check if there's any script that might destroy the GUI.