# Can anyone help me with my "GnomeCode" Script? The error message I get states the following:

Tags: function, testing, lua, roblox, infinite

```
18:13:51.541  Infinite yield possible on 'ReplicatedStorage.Events:WaitForChild("GetData")'  -  Studio
  18:13:51.541  Stack Begin  -  Studio
  18:13:51.541  Script 'ServerScriptService.Datastore', Line 9  -  Studio - Datastore:9
  18:13:51.541  Stack End  -  Studio
```

My Script Looks like This:

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")

local database = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("database")
local functions = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")
local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Functions")
local getDataFunc = functions:WaitForChild("GetData")
local exitEvent = events:WaitForChild("ExitGame")

local MAX_SELECTED_TOWERS = 5

local data = {}

local function LoadData(player)
    local success = nil
    local playerData = nil
    local attempt = 1

    repeat
        success, playerData = pcall(function()
            return database:GetAsync(player.UserId)
        end)
    
        attempt += 1
        if not success then
            warn(playerData)
            task.wait()
        end
    
    until success or attempt == 3

    if success then
        print("Connection Success")
        if not playerData then
            print("New Player, Giving Default Data")
            playerData = {
                ["Credits"] = 175,
                ["SelectedTowers"] = {"Iron Man MK5"},
                ["OwnedTowers"] = {"Iron Man MK5", "Wolverine"}
            }
        end
        data[player.UserId] = playerData
    else
        warn("Unable to get data for player", player.UserId)
        player:Kick("There was a problem getting your data, We're Sorry!")
    end
end
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(LoadData)

local function SaveData(player)
    if data[player.UserId] then
        local success = nil
        local playerData = nil
        local attempt = 1

        repeat
            success, playerData = pcall(function()
                return database:UpdateAsync(player.UserId, function()
                    return data[player.UserId]
                end)
            end)

            attempt += 1
            if not success then
                warn(playerData)
                task.wait()
            end

        until success or attempt == 3

        if success then
            print("Data Saved Successfully")
        else
            warn("Unable to get save data for", player.UserId)
        end
    else
        warn("No Session Data For", player.UserId)
    end

end
exitEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player)
    SaveData(player)
    data[player.UserId] = nil
end)

game:BindToClose(function()
    if not RunService:IsStudio() then
        for index, player in pairs(Players:GetPlayers()) do
                task.spawn(function()
                SaveData(player)
            end)
        end
    else
        print ("Shutting Down Inside Studio")
    end
end)


getDataFunc.OnServerInvoke = function(player)
    return data[player.UserId]
end
```

If Anyone Knows How to Fix This I will be so appreciative, thank you.

Im making a Tower Defense Game using "GnomeCodes" Tower Defense Tutorial Videos, Im on the last one and on the section "Getting Players Chosen Towers" so thats what im expecting to happen but whenever I play test it, The Towers are blank and no where to be seen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i fix Infinite yield possibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471149/how-do-i-fix-infinite-yield-possibility)

Answer (score 0):

local functions = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")

- supposed to be functions like this local functions = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Functions")
  local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Functions") - supposed to be events like this local events = ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild("Events")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Same

I think your get data function in replicated doesn't exit. make sure the name is *exactly* the same as the one in the events folder in replicated

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).