Infinite yield possible on 'ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules")' in Leaderstats code
Whenever I try running this Data Manager Module script I get a script error saying:
Infinite yield possible on 'ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules")'  -  Studio

But for some reason the leaderboard works fine, just the rolls are not appearing next to my name in the leader board.

Also I tried adding a 1 to the rolls in the Template module script but that did not work either so I just set it back to 0.
I tried asking an AI bot and it told me that this issue might be caused of the loading time, so I tried changing the script line:3 in Data Manager to :
local modules = ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("Modules", 5) -- waits up to 5 seconds

and the same error occurs :

Infinite yield possible on 'ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules")'  -  Studio

If anyone could help me solve the problem, I would be very thankful. I will put the rest of my scripts down below, Player data, Leader Stats, the Template and the server script. All of which I reread and re-scripted.




If you need any other info to solve this please let me know I will gladly provide any script just ask! :D
What I tried: Running Data Manager Module script
What I Expected: The leaderboard at the top right of the screen to show the amount of times a player has rolled in the game.
What actually resulted: Script error Infinite yield possible on 'ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules")'  -  Studio

https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode - Please copy and paste your code into your question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471149/how-do-i-fix-infinite-yield-possibility

It seems like you are waiting for Modules twice in the DataManager script according to the error.
Infinite yield possible on 'ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules")

The error states you are using ServerScriptService.Modules:WaitForChild("Modules") when you want to use ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("Modules").
Try using the below code in the script, DataManager. I corrected it so it properly waits for Modules now.
local ServerScriptService = game:GetService("ServerScriptService")

require(ServerScriptService:WaitForChild("Modules"):WaitForChild("DataManager"))


-- game.ServerScriptService.Modules.PlayerData
require(script.Parent.DataManager)


you should add context to explain your answer.
